# Closed shape from several curves

Tags: vector, affinity-designer

I’m creating a shape that is composed of several curves, but I’d like to apply a consistent fill to the whole thing. In this case, the bounds of the outline curves overlap, so one will get partially occluded if I simply apply a fill to each curve. Is there any way to do this other than creating a separate shape below the outline curves and applying a fill for that? That’d work, but then if I want to make tweaks later on I’ll have to adjust both shapes.

I’m using Affinity Designer on iPad, but I imagine there’s some generic solution for this kind of problem. I’m new to this sort of art so hopefully there’s something basic I’m missing. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Affinity user, however I can still answer this, since it doesn't really matter what vector image editor you are using. They all work basically the same.  The example below was created with Illustrator.

I think you have painted yourself into a corner, so to speak.

Instead, consider changing the way the vector is constructed.  The foot should be a single closed shape, toes included. The lines to separate the toes can be separate lines (shown in blue).

This of course means you will probably have to use the Pen tool, because you will need to create some corner point nodes to make the toes.

Then you will be able to fill the closed shape to solve the problem.

[image]